# Error in TensorFlow.js Face Landmarks Detection when developing a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, typescript, tensorflow, google-chrome-extension, tensorflow.js

I am currently working on developing a chrome extension using face landmarks detection from TensorFlow.js.

When trying to load the script from mediapipe in my Chrome extension, I receive the following error:

> "Refused to load the script 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/face_mesh/face_mesh_solution_packed_assets_loader.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: 'script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' //localhost::*'. Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback."

Does someone have any idea how to fix it?

Here is the manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Face Detection Model",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "My Chrome Extension",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/face_mesh/face_mesh_solution_packed_assets_loader.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "https://*/*"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon_16.png",
    "32": "icons/icon_32.png",
    "48": "icons/icon_48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon_128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_title": "Model",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "videoCapture",
    "runtime",
    "pointerLock"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "contentScript.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' http://localhost:* http://127.0.0.1:*; object-src 'self'",
    "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' http://localhost:* http://127.0.0.1:*; object-src 'self'"
  }
}
```

I have attempted various solutions to resolve this error, such as modifying the Content Security Policy (CSP) in the manifest file, but I keep encountering the same issue. I am using Manifest Version 3 for my Chrome extension.